# How to disable vertical / horizontal mouse movement in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to prevent an object from moving vertically on the surface when moving the mouse around while horizontal movements will still be allowed.

How do I do that?

I have managed to let the object move around freely using:

```
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            x, y = event.pos
```

But don't know how disable y from responding and allow only x to move.

Any advice will be appreciated.

BTW - I have read similar questions but nothing was related specifically to this issue.

Comment: Replace y with another letter, tada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember much of Pygame, so I might be missing something, but it looks kinda obvious:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
    x = event.pos[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Hi You can use this:

```
#first  get the pos of mouse :
mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
#then set the position:
pygame.mouse.set_pos(anyconstantvalue,mousey)
#make sure you set a constant for as ive mentioned above.
#this will allow you to move only in y direction. You can do the vice versa for x direction.
```